# How can I "preview layout" of an xml file on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, adt, eclipse-adt

I am creating a bunch of layout files and would like to preview roughly what they will look like on the Android.  Is there a way to do this? and if so, what would be the best way?

Right now, I have to boot up the device and navigate to the Activity every time in order to see the layout.  Also, it looks like the  preview of Eclipse is not ideal as it doesn't display things correctly (is this the best it gets?)

Comment: Shameless self promotion. Have you tried jimu Mirror? http://jimulabs.com I think it's exactly what you wanted as described above, except it's an accurate preview, not rough one. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Dummy Activity, and set the intent MAIN to it.

When you want to test how that activity looks like, just setLayout on onCreate to the xml that you want to test and you will see it.

I also don't trust in Eclipse preview, and AVDs are really slow, so I attach an android device and use a dummy activity to test layouts

Answer (score 4):

You can use the utility at http://www.droiddraw.org/.

Simply copy and paste your layout xml at the Output window, and click "Load". This works both ways.

Comment: Except that DroidDraw doesn't work very well and the last change was June 2012 (it is now December 2014).  Pity because it looked like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Besides running on a real device or in the emulator, Eclipse's preview is the best it gets. Make sure you set the right options for screen size and API version in the preview screen; that sometimes helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Activity like this:

```
//add the imports

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Ask for a full screen window
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onStart()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        // Get the info about the screen

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Change the `activity_main` layout and you can test any layout clicking in `Graphical Layout` of your `xml`.

If you don't trust in `Eclipse`-preview and you want to avoid the slow `Android emulator`, try to enable the `Virtualization` (Intel processors). You must install the packages `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM)` and `Intel x86` `System-Image`. Next, you can create an `AVD` using that System-Image and the emulator will speed up.

Otherwise, if you haven't got a capable Virtualization processor, I'm sorry for you, but you must trust in Eclipse preview ;)

Bye!

Answer (score 0):

Add as parameter of ListView in xml file following line:

**tools:listitem="@layout/my_custom_list_item"**

where my_custom_list_item is layout you want to use as list item.